# backslashdot (\.) appears as dot (.)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

I was writing the the code below with the `b` and `pre` tags for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32964964/1122270) to [nginx location deny by file extension syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32960967/1122270):

```
location ~* .(bak|zip)$|/. {
    deny all;
}
```

Which appears different with `<b><pre>` than the 4-space indented version:

```
location ~* \.(bak|zip)$|/\. {
    deny all;
}
```

Removing the code for the minimal test case leaves us with just the *backslashdot*:

```
.
```

Actually, even without `<b><pre>`, just the backslashdot (.) alone is shown as just the dot (.)!

Now, why does `\.` appears as `.` instead?

Comment: @Pat no, that other one is about comments. This one here is about posts.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a duplicate if this is quite a different context and different character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Markdown, backslashes trigger escaping, to avoid interpreting special characters as special.

However, when inside a code block (indenting every line by 4 spaces), that escaping behaviour is disabled, to allow true verbatim display. This does not apply if you're writing your own `<pre>` tags by hand, however; all the standard Markdown rules apply in that case.

Answer (score 4):

When using the `<pre>`tag, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
<b><pre>
location ~* \\.(bak|zip)$|/\\. {
    deny all;
}
</pre></b>
```

Will result in:

```
location ~* \.(bak|zip)$|/\. {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: I've already noticed it myself, but why?

Comment: That's how markdown works, guess we just have to accept it. :)

Comment: @cnst It's so that you can escape the markdown formatting characters like `\_\_\_` -- without the backslashes that would be misinterpreted.